Transit visa for UK
I will be travelling to Mumbai from Halifax via London by Air Canada, the layover is for 16 hours and the flight lands there (Heathrow) at 8:30pm and takes off on the next day at 1pm for Mumbai.
I don’t intend to stay at any hotel overnight and am wondering if I will still require an Airside/Visitor in Transit Visa for UK?
I am Canadian PR with a valid US visitor visa and Indian Passport.
